# Flutter: Error says - Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings while trying to navigate to another screen

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-navigation

Although questions with such error messages exist in this site, none solves my problem.
I have a button and on clicking the button, I just need to go to a different screen. But when ever I tap on the screen, the error shows up.

I first setup a route in `MaterialApp` and then tried to navigate to that route on tapping the button. The full code and the error message are given below:

**Code:**

```
import 'livesession1to1.dart';


class NavigationService {
  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}



Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: CountDownTimer(),
    navigatorKey: NavigationService.navigatorKey, // set property// Added by me later from prev project
    // initialRoute: "/",

    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
      '/liveSession1to1': (context) =>LiveSession1to1(),
    },
  )
  );
}// end of main

class CountDownTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  const CountDownTimer();

  final String? title='';

  @override
  _CountDownTimerState createState() => _CountDownTimerState();
}



class _CountDownTimerState extends State<CountDownTimer> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }// end of initstate




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Live Session'),
      ),
      body: Text('Demo Text'),

      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

        children: [
          _button(title: "Go", onPressed: () =>
          Navigator.of(context ,rootNavigator: true).pushNamed('/liveSession1to1', arguments: {'room_found': 123 } )
          ),


        ],
      ),

      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }

  Widget _button({required String title, VoidCallback? onPressed}) {
    return Expanded(
        child: TextButton(
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
          ),

          onPressed: onPressed,
        ));
  }
}
```

**Error found:**

The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:

Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/liveSession1to1", {room_found: 123}) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate
this route.
Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:

1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
   Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.

***So how to solve the problem ?***

Answer (score 0):

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

void main() {
  locatorSetup();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _navService = locator<NavigationHandler>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
        navigatorKey: _navService.navigatorKey,
        // I don't know what your first screen is, so I'm assuming it's a Splash Screen
        home: SplashScreen());
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  final _navService = locator<NavigationHandler>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _navService.pushNamed(Routes.LiveSession1to1);
        },
        child: Text("Go to next page"),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class LiveSession1to1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const LiveSession1to1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LiveSession1to1> createState() => _LiveSession1to1State();
}

class _LiveSession1to1State extends State<LiveSession1to1> {
  final _navService = locator<NavigationHandler>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _navService.goBack();
        },
        child: Text("Go to previous page"),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void locatorSetup() {
  locator
      .registerLazySingleton<NavigationHandler>(() => NavigationHandlerImpl());
}

Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case Routes.LiveSession1to1:
      return _getPageRoute(view: LiveSession1to1(), routeName: settings.name);
    default:
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}'),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}

PageRoute _getPageRoute({String? routeName, Widget? view}) {
  return MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: RouteSettings(
      name: routeName,
    ),
    builder: (_) => view!,
  );
}

class Routes {
  static const String LiveSession1to1 = "liveSession1to1";
}

abstract class NavigationHandler {
  ///Pushes `destinationRoute` route onto the stack
  Future<dynamic>? pushNamed(String destinationRoute, {dynamic arg});

  ///Pushes `destinationRoute` onto stack and removes stack items until
  ///`lastRoute` is hit
  Future<dynamic>? pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      String destinationRoute, String lastRoute,
      {dynamic arg});

  ///Pushes `destinationRoute` onto stack with replacement
  Future<dynamic>? pushReplacementNamed(String destinationRoute, {dynamic arg});

  ///Pushes `destinationRoute` after popping current route off stack
  Future<dynamic>? popAndPushNamed(String destinationRoute, {dynamic arg});

  ///Pops current route off stack
  void goBack();

  ///Pops routes on stack until `destinationRoute` is hit
  void popUntil(String destinationRoute);

  ///Exits app
  void exitApp();

  late GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;
}

/// Handles navigation
class NavigationHandlerImpl implements NavigationHandler {
  @override
  late GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  /// Constructs a NavigationHandler instance
  NavigationHandlerImpl({GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? navigatorKey}) {
    this.navigatorKey = navigatorKey ?? GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  }

  NavigatorState? get state => navigatorKey.currentState;

  @override
  void exitApp() {
    SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
  }

  @override
  void goBack() {
    if (state != null) {
      return state!.pop();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future? popAndPushNamed(String destinationRoute, {arg}) {
    if (state != null) {
      return state!.popAndPushNamed(destinationRoute, arguments: arg);
    }
  }

  @override
  void popUntil(String destinationRoute) {
    if (state != null) {
      return state!.popUntil(ModalRoute.withName(destinationRoute));
    }
  }

  @override
  Future? pushNamed(String destinationRoute, {arg}) {
    if (state != null) {
      return state!.pushNamed(destinationRoute, arguments: arg);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future? pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(String destinationRoute, String lastRoute,
      {arg}) {
    if (state != null) {
      return state!.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        destinationRoute,
        ModalRoute.withName(lastRoute),
        arguments: arg,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Future? pushReplacementNamed(String destinationRoute, {arg}) {
    if (state != null) {
      return state!.pushReplacementNamed(destinationRoute, arguments: arg);
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Here is a clip]

Comment: I pasted all your code before the `main()` function. And the same error exists. BTW I used  `"/liveSession1to1"` instead of `"liveSession1to1"` in the `Routes` class. I omitted `routes:` from`MaterialApp` as well.

Comment: I have added what the Material App widget should look like

Comment: No luck. Same prob exists.

Comment: That's really strange, it should work though, although I have a navigation handler but I don't think the navigation handler would change anything.

Comment: No, it did not solve the problem. There should be as the first argument `context` in `Navigator.pushNamed(`, right ? Waiting for a quick solution from you.

Comment: How to make your solution work ?

Comment: Any fix from you ?

Comment: I have honestly forgotten about this issue. lol.

Comment: I have changed the entire code.